# Linking Containers in POD in K8S

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I want to link my selenium/hub container to my chrome and firefox node containers in a POD.

In docker, it was easily defined in the docker compose yaml file.
I want to know how to achieve this linking in kubernetes.

This is what appears on the log.: [image: logs]
This is the error image: [image: error]

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: mytestingpod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: seleniumhub
    image: selenium/hub
    ports:
    - containerPort: 4444
    hostPort: 4444
  - name: chromenode
    image: selenium/node-chrome-debug
    ports:
    - containerPort: 5901
    links: seleniumhub:hub
  - name: firefoxnode
    image: selenium/node-firefox-debug
    ports:
    - containerPort: 5902
    links: seleniumhub:hub
```

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFjNC.png):

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use **[kompose](http://kompose.io/)** described in "[Translate a Docker Compose File to Kubernetes Resources](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tools/kompose/user-guide/)": it will translate your `docker-compose.yml` file into kubernetes yaml files.

You will then see how the  selenium/hub container declaration is translated into kubernetes config files.

Note though that [docker link](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/) are obsolete.
Try instead to follow the [kubernetes examples/selenium](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/examples/selenium) which are [described here](https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/blob/master/staging/selenium/README.md).

The way you connect applications with Kubernetes is through a service:
See "[Connecting Applications with Services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/connect-applications-service/)".

Comment: Even after using kompose i am getting the error that chrome is not linked to a running hub container

Comment: Also with kompose mulitple pods are created with single containers in them , what i want is a single pod with multi containers

Comment: @adityarawat can you edit your question with the exact error message as well as the yaml file content?

Comment: @adityarawat I have edited my answer accordingly. Using link does not seem to be the recommended approach.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to link them. The way Kubernetes works, [all the containers in the same Pod are already on the same networking namespace](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod/#resource-sharing-and-communication), meaning that they can just talk to each other through `localhost` and the right port.

> The applications in a pod all use the same network namespace (same IP and port space), and can thus “find” each other and communicate using localhost. Because of this, applications in a pod must coordinate their usage of ports. Each pod has an IP address in a flat shared networking space that has full communication with other physical computers and pods across the network.

If you want to access the `chromenode` container from the `seleniumhub` container, just send a request to localhost:5901.

If you want to access the `seleniumhub` container from the `chromenode` container, just send a request to localhost:4444.

Comment: How will i request to the localhost:4444 or 5901 ? Do i have to specify request in yaml file?

Comment: I don't know how seleniumhub works, but I guess you were specifying `hub` somewhere in the `seleniumhub` configuration to connect to the chrome or firefox node, right? Instead of using `hub` , use localhost and the port.